# Issue in sighandler

Tags: c, multithreading

I am creating a user level thread library implementing preemptive round robin scheduler. I have the handler function like this:

```
 void handler(int signum)
 {
   gtthread_yield();   
 }
```

In the gtthread_yield, i am doing the context switching to switch to the next thread to be executed. The logic works fine in most cases. But, i am getting a segmentation fault when the signal is raised even before the gtthread_yield function (called from sighandler) could finish executing. Because of this , my code accesses invalid memory location (memory that i had already freed)

Is there any way to avoid handler being raised before the gtthread_yield function finishes execution?

Thanks

Comment: what is gtthread_yield? is it async signal safe?

Comment: No,it is not. It is just a normal function

Answer (score 1):

Use [`sigaction()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) and its helpers (`sigemptyset()`, `sigfillset()`, `sigaddset()`, etc.) to block signals while the handler is in progress.  That is probably a necessary step; it may not be sufficient.  If it is not sufficient, you probably need to revise the signal handling so that it does almost nothing except a `volatile sig_atomic_t` variable before returning.  Then the calling code has to look at the atomic variable and call `gtthread_yield()` when it is set (remembering to clear the variable after returning from `gtthread_yield()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can block other signals for the handler duration, see e.g. [this entry in glibc manual](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_21.html#SEC373) how to do it.